# Get arguments from stack using EBP

Tags: c++, c, assembly

I need some help here, I am a novice in assemly language.
What I have done so far.
Assembler code :

```
extern puts
section .data
    test: db 'test',0

section .text
    global main
main:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov ecx, [ebp+12]
    push ecx
    call puts

    pop ecx

    mov eax,0
    leave
    ret 0x80
```

SO: `Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS`, gcc version `4.8.2`
Assemble with nasm : `nasm -f elf32 2lab.asm` and compile with gcc `gcc -lc -m32 2lab.o -o 2lab`

Object dump of section main `objdump -dS -M intel-mnemonic 2lab`

```
080484a0 <main>:
 80484a0:       55                      push   ebp
 80484a1:       89 e5                   mov    ebp,esp
 80484a3:       8b 4d 08                mov    ecx,DWORD PTR [ebp+0xc]
 80484a6:       51                      push   ecx
 80484a7:       e8 44 fe ff ff          call   80482f0 <puts@plt>
 80484ac:       59                      pop    ecx
 80484ad:       b8 00 00 00 00          mov    eax,0x0
 80484b2:       c9                      leave  
 80484b3:       c2 80 00                ret    0x80
```

Run it `./2lab firstArg`, output is `��������` and if I replace `mov ecx, [ebp+12]` with `mov ecx, [ebp+8]` the result is `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

Where I go wrong ? I would appreciate if you answer in a detailed manner.
As it is [here](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Disassembly/Functions_and_Stack_Frames) and [here](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv-asm.html), I don't know what I have missed.
Thanks!

Comment: 2lab.asm? This sounds like homework.

Comment: @MattD At least he's given it a go and has shown his working

Comment: @MattD, it is not a homework. I have missed some of the labs and I want to understand on my own.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that the prototype for `main` is `int main(int argc, char** argv)`. Notice the type of `argv` is `char**`. You want `puts(argv[1])` but you are effectively doing `puts(argv)`. Knowing that `argv[1]` by definition means `*(argv + 1)` and that C pointer arithmetic is scaled by the item size, you need to replace `push ecx` with `push dword [ecx + 4]`.

PS: `ret 0x80` is wrong, you probably mixed `ret` and `int 0x80` together. You just want `ret` here.

Comment: Pretty sure he is supposed to reference test declared up in his data segment, not command line args.

Comment: @MattD The title says `get argument from stack`, and also the invocation with `firstArg` hints that he wants that argument.

Comment: Ah I see. It would be nice if what was sought was spelled out for us by the poster, beyond "help me".

Comment: @MattD, initially I have used puts to print the test label. I have make a syscall `mov eax,4 ... int 0x80` to print the value. Sorry for my English, I am not a native speaker.

Answer (score 0):

Your string argument to puts() is likely wrong. Check its API and be sure you are loading the right arguments. String functions like puts() read their input until they reach a null terminator. If they don't find one and read memory out of bounds, you will seg fault.